# Reverse Proxy Appliance

Tags: reverse-proxy

The company at which I am working is looking to upgrade their reverse proxies from an old FreeBSD install. We just installed Cisco IronPort appliances for standard web filtering and we really like the way these things work. We are looking for something similar to do reverse proxying.

Requirements are :

- Simplicity of configuration
- Easy clustering capabilities
- Speed

I do not have unlimited budget obviously but I am looking for a decent solution. I am looking for a range of products which explains why I have not included any statistics.

Thank you for your help,

Antoine Benkemoun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some very good alternatives

- F5 Networks Big-IP with Application Security Module
- Imperva Securesphere Web Application Firewall
- Barracuda Web Application Firewall

Answer (score 1):

I have been very happy with Bluecoat's range of products for proxying

Comment: Which of their product line does Reverse Proxying ? They have quite a few...

Comment: I believe all of their ProxySG line can function as both a forward and reverse proxy